# Bluetooth parking

Tags: bluetooth

How do I park a Bluetooth connection? I'm trying to communicate with dozens of Bluetooth devices, and the time to re-establish a connection is unacceptable. I've read that you can park connections, but not found anything that answers how to do this.

Comment: Could you be more specific about whether you are trying to park connections or device pairs?

Answer (score 1):

I know that you can park a connection if it's on the MS Bluetooth stack. There is a nice API you can use called 32feet.Net. It lets you set the socket options. Here's a quick link to the [documentation](http://community.inthehand.com/library/InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocketOptionNameMembers.html). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have been creating firmware for Bluetooth modules since 2000 and can honestly say that I have never used Park nor has any customer asked for it.
My advice, as per others in this trail, keep away from it. Perhaps Hold mode is worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Parking mode is one of connected state mode, explained in the core Bluetooth spec, right from early 1.1 or so. Please follow up with various sniff modes as well, including the newer ones such as sniff sub rating. Other than park modes, you have hold modes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the parking mode will be removed in next Bluetooth version(Bluetooth 5).

And, the park and hold mode are *seems* a beautiful  way to save power but  in real life, due to the IOP issue, not too much device can "really" support such kind of power save mode in market. The most common used mode is sniff but this already beyond your request.

So, just forget park mode.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an Bluetooth ACL connection with a device. If your device is the master, then you can use link layer message LMP_park.

Usually you can do this from application using HCI command
HCI_Park_Mode (Connection_Handle,
Beacon_Max_Interval, Beacon_Min_Interval)

http://affon.narod.ru/BT/bluetooth_app_c9.pdf